# Confused about the definition of EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am reading EJB 3 in Action and I came across this sentence

> In very straightforward terms, Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) is a platform for building portable, reusable and scalable business applications using the Java programming language.

Then in the next two paragraphs they make a difference of EJB as a component and EJB as a framework.

Further they say that when they talk about EJBs in the book they are referring to the server-side components that you use to build parts of your application.

I am confused about what EJB is, is it correct that EJB is a platform/framework, and the components and container are both included in that definition? And would it be more correct to say EJB components than just EJBs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am confused about what EJB is, is it correct that EJB is a platform/framework,

Yes ... among other things.

> and the components and container are both included in that definition?

Yes.

> And would it be more correct to say EJB components than just EJBs?

That's debatable.  (And a pointless debate, IMO.)

The bottom line is that term EJB means lots of things depending on the context and who is talking.  When someone says "EJB" you have to consider the context to determine the meaning.  But, hey, human language is like that.